# Can anybody identify these small, red insects?

Tags: identification, insects

What kind of bugs are these? Are they good or bad for plants? Do they bite?

[image: Small red bugs]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe they are [newly hatched Leptoglossus nymphs](http://www.austinbug.com/coreidae.html) -- scroll down ⅔ of that page to see images (reproduced below seeing as I'm unable to find any kind of Copyright notice on that site)...

[image]
[image]

> The [genus Leptoglossus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leptoglossus) contains the classic leaf-footed bugs. The hind tibiae have large flared processes that resemble the shape of leaves. When these insects fly, their back legs hang down and they are easily mistaken for wasps, which also drag their hind legs in flight. They also buzz like wasps. In fact, this genus seems to have several tricks for discouraging predators. **The nymphs are orange and black, a universal warning signal indicating bad taste or toxins in the insect world. They frequently feed in groups, which enhances the visual effect of the colors.**

They feed on plants... therefore are not considered beneficial. They should be removed via:

- An appropriate insecticide.
- By hand picking -- personally I think I would got with that option or I might be tempted to get the vacuum out and suck them up...

Also check the plant for any eggs (unhatched) and remove them...

Comment: Would insecticidal soap kill these also?

Answer (score 0):

I found these bugs on one of my plants. I sprayed them with water and a little dawn dishing washing liquid. They died right away.

Answer (score -1):

Assassin Bug, I think, or at least some where in that family. I find them around my house in SE Texas, on window seals. I do also see these insects in the garden.

Comment: Don't seem to fit the description of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduviidae