# Bug Identification - Anyone know what kind of bugs these are?

Tags: bugs

Saw a group of these bugs on my basil plants this morning. There are also a few on the mint. They don't look like mites or aphids and they don't appear to be eating it, but I am curious if any one knows what they are and if I should start trying to get rid of them. Thank you![image]

Comment: Roughly what part of the world are you?

Comment: How did you get them to line up like that :-)

Comment: @Peter4075 I'm pretty sure they have been drilled at night  by a Gumby Cat (if you know, you know. You know?)

Comment: They look a lot like the bugs in this question: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2128/can-anybody-identify-these-small-red-insects

Comment: These are young harlequin bugs, or very similar. Bad for plants…